# What might be the reason to use Func<T> in property instead of simple T

Tags: c#, properties, func

I've seen in code such properties:

```
public static Func<string> TabMainDataToolTip
{
    get
    {
        return (Func<string>) (() => "Main Data");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** in some places the actual `string` value is retrieved from application resources (localization).

What is the reason to return `Func<T>` instead of just type `T`? Does it give any advantage?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

Comment: Well, the only thing I can see in this case - it allows you to 'execute' property like a method `var text = TabMainDataToolTip();` and that will confuse everybody. Looks like product of obfuscation.

Comment: Does it look exactly same in your code? Or maybe you did some simplification before pasting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific example there is no advantage, just extra overhead.

In general, this technique allows deferring the calculation of the final result until it is really needed. For example, some kinds of tooltips might want to include "expensive" information in their text -- perhaps the tooltip needs data that has to be fetched from a web service.

This scheme allows the property getter's caller to get hold of something that is "as good as" the final result without forcing them to evaluate that result on the spot. The caller could then decide to evaluate the result later, or evaluate it in parallel using a worker thread, or anything else it might want to do.

Answer (score 5):

`Func<T>` Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of the type specified by the TResult parameter. You can use this delegate to represent a method, whereas  **T** can be used to represent a **type**.

Answer (score 2):

`Func<TResult>` is a predefined delegate in .NET.

A method conforming to this delegate will have return type `TResult`:

```
TResult someMethod(){}
```

The code you posted:

```
public static Func<string> TabMainDataToolTip
{
    get
    {
        return (Func<string>) (() => "Main Data");
    }
}
```

means that the property `TabMainDataToolTip` returns a **method with return type of** `string`.

In this case, said method is:

```
() => "Main Data"
```

equivalent to:

```
string anonymousMethod()
{
   return "Main Data";
}
```

There are actually **16 variants of the Func delegate**, taking from 0 (zero) to 15 parameters and returning 1 result.

Example:

```
Func<T,TResult>
```

means a method like this:

```
TResult someMethod(T parameterName)
{
   return someTResultOject;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jon's answer, your code is consumed like this:

```
string mainData = TabMainDataToolTip();
```

Notice the parentheses. This is counter-intuitive for a property.

A better implementation would be based on `Lazy<T>`:

```
    private static readonly Lazy<string> TabMainDataToolTipFactory = new Lazy<string>(() => "Main Data");

    public static string TabMainDataToolTip
    {
        get
        {
            return TabMainDataToolTipFactory.Value;
        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```
string mainData = TabMainDataToolTip;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, there are times when you may need some info/state at the time the `Func` is called. For example, you may need the `DateTime.Now` when the `Func` is called. You also may need to do some additional work. For example, if it is Tuesday, return one string otherwise return another.

Another reason you may want a `Func` is because in some cases it may be called but in other cases it may never be called and thus the code within the `Func` may never be executed.

Comment: Its a proper answer for general usage question with any type. In my case, for string, it looks more like an overhead, or auto-generated code.

Comment: Yes in your case, it may not make sense or it may. It depends on the class the `Func` is passed to and what the class does with it. I know it is asking for just a string but consider the flexibility: The designer may have thought that you may need some state at the exact time the func is called. It is hard to say.

Comment: If you are familiar with NewtonSoft JSON library, you will notice `JsonConvert` has a property `Func<JsonSerializerSettings> DefaultSettings` which is a `Func`. It does not need to be a `Func` but since it is, it gives the flexibility to return different things depending on when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

`Func<T>` is just like any other method which will return T. In your case string.

This will help you to pass the entire method as a parameter to any other method.

You can find more info on this delegate here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Most people prefer using `Func<T>` , if they are developing any API.

But the above sample makes no sense.